# Why do td and th of the 'table' element behave so abnormally and illogically when you apply to them width in percentage?

Tags: css

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

In this example, I am applying width of 100% to table, td and th, and I don't understand the outcome. Why is the first th and td taking all the space while the last th and td are shrunk at the end?

If I use smaller percentage, it works as expected.

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

In the next example, I remove the 'table', and only set the width of 100% to th and td, and the result is the same, BUT, if I now start reducing the width in percentage, they behave in a very illogical way. Seemingly the more I increase the percentage, the more the table enlarges. At 10% the table size is clearly larger than half the screen, but at 50%, it's closet to 100px.

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

I understand that th and td are child-elements, and the table element has like a family of tags that work together, but still, is there some logic behind this outcome, or is it completely random and illogical, and purely the result of the tag family not working together?

Note that, th and th work as expected if you use width in pixels instead.

Comment: _"Why is the first th and td taking all the space while the last th and td are shrunk at the end?"_ Because you set every table element to be 100% width

Comment: what result would you expect ? if both are 100% of width, then the parent is twice bigger , then what ? turn down to 50% or fight each other or let the (w)hole thing go nuts on an infinite loop ?

Comment: add a third column to your last snippet ... you need to understand that what you try to do is not coherent at all and browser do their best. Again , what result do you expect ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That doesn't really answer my question. When I set the width of th, td to 50%, the table shrinks to less than 100px. Is that an expected behavior? Does setting the width to 100% applies to the first two elements, and that's why they extend all the way? Why doesn't it apply to the first element only? Why first two? And what is it not exactly 100%, but a little bit less just enough space for the other two to be squeezed there? I want to understand what is happening.

Comment: If you truly want to understand how tables are sized, I suggest reading [the algorithm in the HTML standard that discusses exactly that](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/tabular-data.html#forming-a-table).

Comment: these are comments, no answers.. and no , none of your cells are 100% of the table, else there would be one column hidden out of two

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I just added another th, and another td. At 50%, they went from about 100px, to all the way to the end, and the first two columns take all the space, while the last (new 3rd) is now small at the end? If i make it 100% width, again, the first two take all the space, while the other two are small at the end? Why? What tis the logic there?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus yeah, exactly, the first cell isn't 100%, it's something like 90%, while the second is 10%. Why? I don't get the logic here. Why is this happening? Is this abnormal, is it expected behavior, is it bug, what is it?

Comment: there is something about 3x50% being not equal to 100% ... the browser try to follow the idea and each time it does, the table expand, then it tries again to apply width(50%) to each cells  and so on untill it gives up that infinite loop.

Comment: @ILoveCoffee I haven't read it in full. I just know it talks about how widths are calculated after skimming it. Even if I had, it's quite a demand that I summarize something for you; I have a job where I get paid to do these things...

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Okay, thanks bro. I guess this is a mixture of the element not working properly because of the tag family structure, and the way the browser calculates the width in a situation where the parent is undefined. I just randomly made the mistake of setting the width to the th and td, instead of the table, and found this abnormal outcome, and got curious why is it happening. That's all. Didn't really expect anything, just wanted to know the logic behind this outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table layout algorithm is notorious. The CSS 2.2 spec leaves such situations completely undefined. The only alternative we have is the [CSS Table Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-tables-3/) spec which is a draft clearly marked as "Not ready for implementation", but nonetheless does a better job of trying to describe what browsers actually do currently.

[The layout algorithm there](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-tables-3/#content-measure) is very complicated, too complicated to reasonably be summarized here even if I fully understood it, which I don't. It depends on the interaction of multiple minimum, maximum, and preferred widths over multiple passes to determine the final widths.

However, we can see that in the step [intrinsic percentage width of a column](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-tables-3/#intrinsic-percentage-width-of-a-column), it says that the width of each column uses:

> 100% minus the sum of the intrinsic percentage width of **all prior columns** in the table (further left when direction is "ltr" (right for "rtl"))

which clearly favours giving the available width to the earlier columns over the later ones, which is what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try changing 100% to some px value? Cuz if you put it 100% like that then the first td and th will just take up all the space and ended up like what you described